# Замена свойств у нескольких блоков через JS

Tags: javascript, css, html, блок, radio

По странице есть несколько блоков ... Изначально они спрятаны display:none;

При выборе на radio срабатывает функция:

```
    $(function() {
     "use strict";
     $('#d_1').change( function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     $('#helpblock') 
     .css('display', 'block')
     .animate({opacity: 1}, 200);
 });
});
```

Но срабатывает она для первого блока. А как сделать, чтобы остальные id="helpblock" также стали display:block;?

Comment: `class="helpblock" ` и `$('.helpblock')`  Атрибут `id` - уникальный идентификатор DOM-элемента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На странице не может быть двух элементов с одинаковым `id`, а даже если они есть, бразуер будет взаимодействовать только с первым из них ( в вашем случае как раз такое поведение )

Поменяйте `id` на `class`

```
$(function() {
    "use strict";
    $('#d_1').change( function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.helpblock') // поиск по селектору класса
            .css('display', 'block')
            .animate({opacity: 1}, 200);
    });
});

// html
<div class='helpblock'></div>
```